# Link two list into separate list

Tags: list

I need to link two list and display them in a separate list. I refer many sites, all that they did is displaying in a data view. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using custom code
http://sujeewaediriweera.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/list-join-in-sharepoint-2010-using-caml/

Using SharePoint designer 
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/4-minute-screencast-join-view-of-sharepoint-lists.aspx

I'm not sure, you can add both list in to a Single List Other than having a joined data view.Joininglists should happen only for the view operations.

Comment: +1 nice information! I would recommend including more information than just the links but good stuff overall.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this so still trying to figure out the best way to do this. My approach was to create two list. Second list includes look up column to the first list. Then I created a view for the second list that just displays 1 item at the time.

On new page I inserted the first list web part and modified the view however I need it.
Once I was done with that I clicked on the list and choose Insert Related List from Web Part Tools Option ribbon. After that I just adjusted my views and now I have two linked list. Second one displays additional info of selected item from my list.

Was able to do the whole thing in browser with no custom code or modifying anything in designer.